# Add callback to for loop function

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I have a function to which I pass an array or an object, then it looks for specific keys and edits their values accordingly,

```
function iterate(obj, delta) {
        for (var property in obj) {
            if (obj.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
                if (typeof obj[property] == "object") {
                    iterate(obj[property],delta);
                } else {
                   if(property === 'unix_time'){
                    var bee = parseInt(obj[property]);
                    var b = bee + parseInt(delta);
                       obj[property] = b;
                   }
               }                   
            }
        }
    }
```

Basically, it looks for the "unix_time" key and add a number "delta" to it.

Question: When I call it asynchronous, it becomes undefined, How can I add a callback that I can simply use to determine that the function has finished executing. Or maybe should I add a promise to it?

For example when i run this it returns perfectly

```
console.log("new one", obj);
iterate(obj, 3600000)
```

But this is a problem, it becomes undefined

```
        var dd = iterate(obj, 3600000);
        res.status(200).send(JSON.stringify(dd));
```

Comment: You never return anything from the function, so it'll always return `undefined`. I don't know what you mean by *"When i don't wait for it to finish..."*

Comment: You don't need callbacks or promises, since your function is completely synchronous. When it returns, it has finished executing.

Comment: Like @squint has mentioned - You don't return anything from that function and therefore, it will return null.
If you want to know whether your function has passed through the different if statements in your code, add `console.log('whateverYouWant')`, whenever you want it

Comment: @squint i just updated the question with an example

Comment: Your examples do completely different things. In the first one you're logging the object. In the second one you're logging the return value of the `iterate()` function.

Comment: @Tuna, see [my updated answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40320917/2545680)

Comment: You're never calling it "asynchronous". Don't know why you think that. What do you expect the `iterate` function to return? You're not telling us what the output should be. You're not telling us what's actually wrong.

Comment: @squint there was a typo error there, now i think it's clear

Comment: Can you provide `obj` example?

Comment: @YosvelQuintero look at this https://jsfiddle.net/1gmx3kk0/3/

Comment: Your edit changes essentially nothing. In the first one, you log `obj`. In the second one you don't use `obj` anymore but assign the (non-existing) return value of `iterate()` into a new variable and discard `obj`. Why don't you just do `res.status(200).send(JSON.stringify(obj));`?

Comment: @JJJ, yeah, I suggested it in my answer as well as providing a solution to modify `iterate` to return object based on the data sample (which doesn't seem to have nesting), but it's still unclear what  the problem is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, you function is synchronous and it returns immediately after you call it like this:

```
var result = iterate(tree, delta);
```

However, as it's currently written, the `result` variable will have value of `undefined` since your `iterate` function doesn't return anything.

If you have the setup like this:

```
var obj = {...};
iterate(obj, 3600000)
console.log(obj) // correctly outputs modified object
```

It will output modified object, since you're not using here the returned value from the function. However, in this scenario:

```
console.log("new one", iterate(obj, 3600000)); // ouputs `undefined`
```

the returned value is used and it's `undefined`.

Using the use case you provided, you can modify the usage like this:

```
iterate(obj, 3600000);
res.status(200).send(JSON.stringify(obj));
```

and it will work fine. Or you need to modify `iterate` to return value. Provide an example of `obj` so I can write a modification to your `iterate` function.

Modified the `iterate` function:

```
function iterate(obj, delta) {
    obj.forEach(function (element) {
        if (element.hasOwnProperty('unix_time')) {
            element['unix_time'] = parseInt(element['unix_time']) + parseInt(delta);
        }
    });
    return obj;
}
```

Comment: @Tuna, is `obj` always a linear array of objects without netsting?

Comment: @Tuna, if it's always linear without nesting,  check my updated answer at the bottom.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126967/discussion-between-maximus-and-tuna).

Answer (score -1):

I don't know I understand your question. But, if you want to use a callback, you should split this funcion in two. One for main operation and another for recursivity.

i.e.

```
function iterate(obj, delta, callback) {
    interate_recursive(obj, delta);
    if(typeof callback != 'undefined')
         return callback();
    else return obj;
}

function interate_recursive(obj,delta){
    for (var property in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
            if (typeof obj[property] == "object") {
                iterate(obj[property],delta);
            } else {
               if(property === 'unix_time'){
                var bee = parseInt(obj[property]);
                var b = bee + parseInt(delta);
                   obj[property] = b;
               }
           }                   
        }
    }
}
```